# sending POST request

Tags: c++, https, httprequest, boost-asio

I have a problem with sending POST via https. In the code snippet above, the first part (commented) works well. Next part does not: it doesn't send any request.
What do I need to fix it?

P.s Perhaps the problem arises from the fact that my Lib boost does not support HTTPS.

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <boost/asio.hpp>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <fstream>

    char buffer [9999999];

    int main()
    {
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream;
        stream.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(60));
        stream.connect("www.mail.ru","http");
        //stream << "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        //stream << "Host mail.ru\r\n";
        //stream << "User-Agent   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11\r\n";
        //stream << "Accept   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n" ;
        //stream << "Accept-Encoding  gzip,deflate,sdch\r\n";
        //stream << "Accept-Language  en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n";
        //stream <<"Accept-Charset    ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3\r\n";
        //stream << "Cookie   \r\n\r\n";

    stream << "POST https://auth.mail.ru/cgi-bin/auth HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    stream << "Host: auth.mail.ru\r\n";
    stream << "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1\r\n";
    stream << "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n";
    stream << "Accept-Language: ru-ru,ru;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3\r\n";
    stream << "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n";
    stream << "Connection: keep-alive\r\n";
    stream << "Referer: http://mail.ru/\r\n";
    stream << "X-MailRuSputnik: generic\r\n";
    stream << "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    stream << "Content-Length: 59\r\n";

    stream << "Domain=mail.ru&Login=(login)&Password=(password)&level=0\r\n";

        stream.flush();
        using namespace std ;
     // cout << stream.rdbuf();
        ofstream f("output.txt" /*| ios::bin*/);
        f << stream.rdbuf();
        f.close();
        system("pause");
        return 0 ;
    }
```

Comment: What is your problem? What is the question?

Comment: You might also try `stream << "Connection: close\r\n";` because you are providing a Content-Length and you aren't re-using this connection

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

1) Your `POST` line is specifying the full URL when it should be specifying just the host-relative path instead.  Do not specify the URL scheme or hostname in that line.  That is only needed when connecting to proxies.

```
stream << "POST /cgi-bin/auth HTTP/1.1\r\n";
```

2) HTTP headers are terminated by two sequential CRLF pairs, but your code is only sending one CRLF pair between the `Content-Length` header and the body data, and your body data only ends with one CRLF pair (which you do not need), so there is nothing to tell the server when the HTTP request has finished being sent.

```
stream << "Content-Length: 59\r\n"; 
stream << "\r\n"; // <-- add this
```

3) The value of your `Content-Length` header is `59`, but the length of the body data you showed is 58 instead.  That will cause the server to try to read more bytes than you are actually send, preventing a response from being sent (unless the server implements a receive timeout and can then send back an error response).  I suggest you put the body data into a `std::string` and then use its `length()` method to fill in the correct `Content-Length` value dynamically instead of hard-coding it.

```
std::string content = "Domain=mail.ru&Login=(login)&Password=(password)&level=0";
...
stream << "Content-Length: " << content.length() << "\r\n";
stream << "\r\n";

stream << content;
```